# Google Calendar color picker

Tags: android, colors, color-picker

is there a system based method to call one of those color pickers, like in the Google Calendar app? Or do I have it to build it on my own?

[image]

Comment: what do you want the color picker for?

Comment: there is an android color picker http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Comment: http://v4all123.blogspot.ie/2013/06/simple-colorpicker-for-android.html

Comment: I need one to select the color of a Google Maps marker, but i want one with predefined colors, like in the image above.

Comment: So, basically you're looking for [Color Picker Collection](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/colorpickercollection)? This library includes a port of the color picker used in the stock Calendar app. Code samples are provided in the link.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [Color Picker Collection](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/colorpickercollection).

Implementation:

```
ColorPickerDialog colorcalendar = ColorPickerDialog.newInstance(
              R.string.color_picker_default_title, 
              mColor,
              mSelectedColorCal0,
              5,
              Utils.isTablet(this)? ColorPickerDialog.SIZE_LARGE : ColorPickerDialog.SIZE_SMALL);

  //Implement listener to get selected color value
  colorcalendar.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onColorSelected(int color) 
                {
                   // ADD MARKER
                   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_mobileedge_navpoint);
                   bmp = changeBitmapColor(bmp, color);

                   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("My Spot")
                    .snippet("This is my spot!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
                }

    });

  colorcalendar.show(getFragmentManager(),"cal");
```

Function to change bitmap color:

```
 private Bitmap changeBitmapColor(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int color) {

        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
                sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color, 1);
        p.setColorFilter(filter);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, p);

        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

I tested and it worked fine! The marker has to be all white with alpha, only then is that the colors will be perfect!

Comment: Can u please elaborate on the same

Comment: @prat elaborate what?

Comment: I am also having the same requirement as stated above. The library which u have stated matches my requirement. Can u please help me the usage of library.?

Comment: It will be a great help...also u can check my current question which will give proper scenario